# How to copy a specific Column in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a new table and i want to copy two columns from my other table. How does this work guys? thanks :D

here is the image of my table and the columns I want to copy:

[image: Screenshot of columns]

Comment: I think you will regret doing this in the future when you realize the consequences.

Comment: I am just practicing and trying to learn if there is a way. That is all sir :D

Comment: You are not clear. What does "copy two columns from my other table" mean? Please show example input and output. Please use words to explain when a row is in the output as a function of what's in the input. PS Use text not images whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for creating a new table structure along with the data then this should do the work for you I guess:

```
SELECT EMP_PCT
    ,PROJ_NUM 
INTO tblEmployee_Backup
FROM tblEmployee
```

It will create a new table (in this case 'tblEmployee_Backup') for you with the columns (same data type + same data) from the old/existing table that we select.

And if you are looking to insert data into a new structured table from an existing table then this should do the work for you I guess:

```
CREATE TABLE tblEmployee_Backup (
    EMP_PCT FLOAT
    ,PROJ_NUM INT
);
```

Now you have a new table structure. It's time to insert the data from existing table:

```
INSERT INTO tblEmployee_Backup
SELECT EMP_PCT
   ,PROJ_NUM
FROM tblEmployee
```

Hope this helpful :)

Comment: Welcome !! :) Can you mark it as answered, please? :)

Answer (score 0):

One would wonder what you want the two columns to be associated with in the new table.  But if you just want to create a new table that **only** has those two columns, you could create the table with a select statement.

First, create the new table with the columns you want.  Then insert with a select statement:

```
INSERT INTO my_new_table (EMP_PCT, PROJ_NUM)
SELECT EMP_PCT, PROJ_NUM FROM my_old_table
```

Comment: sir I recieved error stating that my select  is "Incorrect syntax near 'select', Expecting ID.

Comment: @RYREN I updated my answer.  First, create the new table that you want to copy into, then, assuming you have the same column names in the new table, you can use the code above to insert from the old table into the new one.